# Склонение существительных

Tags: склонение

Здравствуйте! Как правильно: оценка рыночной и ликвидационной стоимости или стоимостей? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, именно потому, что это принципиально разные понятия, а оборот "рыночная и ликвидационная стоимость" может кого-то ввести в заблуждение, предпочтительно "рыночной и ликвидационной **стоимостей**". Препятствовать этому может только не очень широкое использование множественного числа (как и у многих отвлеченных и "полуотвлеченных" понятий), но в профессиональной речи это вполне употребимо. Так что я - за "стоимостей". Но только в этом конкретном случае. В других надо будет разбираться отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от контекста. Если конкретно требуется вывести две цифры, да ещё сопоставить одну с другой, то лучше "*стоимостей*" - это разные "физические величины". Если же задаются вопросом, какова стоимость имущества в одном и другом аспекте (за сколько можно предлагать на рынке и за сколько можно распродать), то это как бы единый двумерный "вектор" и можно обойтись "*стоимостью*".

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае желательно употребить существительное во множественном числе: **оценка рыночной и ликвидационной стоимостей.**

**По Розенталю,** ед. число подчеркивает **взаимосвязь** предметов (правая и левая рука), а мн. число подчеркивает **их количество** (золотая и серебряная медали). В приведенном примере лучше обозначить количество **различных стоимостей**.

**Похожие примеры**

Использование показателя рентабельности капитала при сравнении **рыночной и бухгалтерской оценок** компаний. Еще одно условие ― преодоление неразвитости **рыночной и производственной инфраструктур**.

**Примечание: начальный ответ изменен по двум причинам:** 1) частотность мн. числа в похожих текстах выше, хотя встречается и ед. число. 2) С учетом рекомендаций Розенталя, кратко и четко сформулированных, именно эту полезную, как я считаю, информацию мне хотелось донести до участников и последующих читателей форума.

Comment: Опечатка, Sibylla!